# Why can't gdb find symbol which IDA can?

Tags: ida, gdb, breakpoint, symbols

I was reversing [this](https://www.mediafire.com/?6kqg3l8yq3cy89z) binary. While I tried to set a breakpoint in `gdb` on `main` function, it couldn't find its definition. Loading up the same binary in IDA shows up `main` method in the `Function` pane. Why isn't gdb being able to find symbol which IDA can?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you provided is a stripped elf executable. A related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885545/how-to-find-the-main-functions-entry-point-of-elf-executable-file-without-any-s). The main issue is that a stripped elf file has no *main* symbol. Instead, the loader uses the *e_entry* header field, which points to the C libs initialization code. When the initialization is done, it will yield execution to the program.

However, IDA is able to reconstruct the entry point by searching for this indirect jump.

Have a look at the very start of the .text section, you will find these lines:

```
 8048637:   68 86 b7 04 08          push   $0x804b786
 804863c:   e8 9f ff ff ff          call   80485e0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 8048641:   f4                      hlt
```

The value being pushed here right before the call to libc's start function is the actual entry point. I hope this helps.